# Natural system of neighborhoods on $X \times Y$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be any topological spaces. Define natural system of neighborhoods on $X \times Y$. Show that on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ it is standard topology defined by euclidean metrics.

Attempt:
$X \times Y$ is all pairs of $x \in X, y \in Y$. The neighbourhoods of all $x$ and $y$ are included in $X$ and $Y$. I suppose, we should take the products of these neighbourhoods. But I don't understand why it works on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I formulated it incorrectly, sorry. I mean, if $U \subset X$ and $V \subset Y$, we should take $U \times V$.

Comment: Now your formulation makes sense, however you still need to allow for arbitrary unions of such sets since the union of sets of this form need not be of this form.

Comment: @LeBtz It the detail I don't really understand. We define the system of neighborhoods, not the base. Why do we need to include all unions?

Comment: Because the union of two neighborhoods must be a neighborhood aswell but isn't in your definition.

Comment: A-ha, but I still don't understand what to do with my definition to make it work properly.

Comment: I already told you. Just take all the sets you wanted to include as neighborhoods but also allow for arbitrary unions of those sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since that open  sets in $R\times R$ are of form $U\times V$, where $U$, $V$ are opens set in $R$, a base for topology on $R\times R$ is give by product $B(x,r_1) \times B(y,r_1)$ of open balls with center $x,y \in R$, this is,  such topology is generated by set of form $\{ (b,c) \in R^2; |b - x| < r_1 and |c - y| < r_1\}$, but such that are open balls of sum norm in $R^2$. Beacuse the euclidian norm and sum norms are equivalent, your generated topologys are equal.